# Having trouble being specific enough to scrape what I want from a tag with Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here's a sample of the html that I want to scrape.

```
<a id="catalogEntry_img3677183" href="http://www.academy.com/shop/pdp/under-armour%E2%84%A2-mens-tide-chaser-short-sleeve-shirt#repChildCatid=4099002" title="Under Armour Men's Tide Chaser Short Sleeve Shirt" onclick="javascript:dlTrackProductGridClicks(&quot;109457178&quot;,&quot;Under Armour Men's Tide Chaser Short Sleeve Shirt&quot;,&quot;3677183&quot;);">
```

And I would like to retrieve the link inside the quotations for the href attribute. Here's the code I wrote.

```
    a_ids = page_soup.findAll("a")

    for a in range(len(a_ids)):
        output = a_ids[a]["href"]
        print(output)
```

However, the results I get from this code includes a bunch of messy stuff from other a tags like below.

```
<a href="http://www.academy.com/shop/pdp/bcg-mens-turbo-mesh-short-sleeve-t-
shirt#repChildCatid=4190420" id="catalogEntry_img4181006" 
onclick="javascript:dlTrackProductGridClicks(&quot;109409336&quot;,&quot;BCG 
Men's Turbo Mesh Short Sleeve T-shirt&quot;,&quot;4181006&quot;);" 
title="BCG Men's Turbo Mesh Short Sleeve T-shirt">
<img alt="BCG Men's Turbo Mesh Short Sleeve T-shirt" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='//content.academy.com/weblib/images/coming-
soon.jpg';" src="//assets.academy.com/mgen/12/10740412.jpg?is=500,500"/>
<div class="product-info-attributes">
<!-- BEGIN AYRPriceDisplay.jspf -->
<div class="z-pricing" id="offerPrice_4181006">
        $9.99           
    </div>
```

I just want the link in the href tag. How can I target the specific link I want? For reference, the url I'm trying to scrape is from here: http://www.academy.com/shop/browse/apparel/mens-apparel/mens-shirts--t-shirts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The len function is not needed since find_all returns a list.

Just do

```
a_ids = soup.find_all("a") 
for a in a_ids:
    output = a["href"]
    print(output)
```

Or even shorter:

```
hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a')]
for a in hrefs:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


page_soup = """<a id="catalogEntry_img3677183" href="http://www.academy.com/shop/pdp/under-armour%E2%84%A2-mens-tide-chaser-short-sleeve-shirt#repChildCatid=4099002" title="Under Armour Men's Tide Chaser Short Sleeve Shirt" onclick="javascript:dlTrackProductGridClicks(&quot;109457178&quot;,&quot;Under Armour Men's Tide Chaser Short Sleeve Shirt&quot;,&quot;3677183&quot;);">"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(page_soup,'html.parser')


a_ids = soup.findAll("a")

for a in range(len(a_ids)):
    output = a_ids[a]["href"]
    print(output)
```

Specifying the parser type is making a difference I think

Comment: You're absolutely right. I got what I needed thanks pyjg.